# possible sum of product of k elements from array(repetitive allowed)

Tags: math, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Given an array of n elements and a number k we have to select k elements from array and calculate sum of all possible product obtained by these k elements (repetitive allowed);
Also two set of k elements must not have all indexes same . means order doesnot matter .

**Note : overflow is handled by Modulo by some Prime;**

**Constraints** :  N<=5000 ; k<=1e18;

e.g ->

arr[]={1,2,3};

k=2

possible k elements ->  1*1 + 1*2 + 1*3 + 2*2 + 2*3 + 3*3  =  25;

**Order doesnt matter** : 1*2 and 2*1 are not different here;

I have **made recursive code but dont know how to convert it to DP .**

```
recur(pos,prod,items)
{
    if(items==k){sum=(sum+prod%prime);return;}

    if(pos==n)return;

    for(int i=0;i<=k-items;i++)
    {
        recur(pos+1,(prod*power(arr[pos],i))%prime,items+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to do your home work is by finding a solution by yourself.

Comment: `k<=1e18; ` really?

Comment: yes it is creating a problem